# allocating a menu icon in the right place

Tags: java, android, xml

I am writing an android program. The first thing I want to make is an menu icon on the top. Here are my codes:
menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/add"
          android:icon="@drawable/plus"
          android:title="Adding"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          android:showAsAction="always"
     />
</menu>
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

</LinearLayout>
```

and myActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    public boolean onCreateMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        return true;
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is the icon is in the middle but I want to put it in the right top and I dont know how...

also I have seen android:actionlayout and android:action-layout... What's the diffrence between these?!

I would be so happy if anyone can answer my question :)

Comment: Are you trying to put the icon on an action bar ?

Comment: Do you even see your Icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.firstactivity_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }
```

Where R.menu.firstactivity_menu should be your menu xml !

Answer (score 1):

The correct method to override is `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`. You inflate the menu in this method and returns true. It should display on the right side of the action bar.